# Python regex - capture text between two words as string, then append to list

Tags: python, regex, loops

This is the structure of the txt file (repeated units of CDS-text-ORIGIN):

```
     CDS             311..>428
                     /gene="PNR"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /product="photoreceptor-specific nuclear receptor"
                     /protein_id="AAD28302.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:4726077"
                     /translation="METRPTALMSSTVAAAAPAAGAASRKESPGRWGLGEDPT"
 ORIGIN
```

I want to pull out the text from 311..<428 to GEDPT" as a string
The regex I have so far is:

```
compiler = re.compile(r"^\s+CDS\s+(.+)ORIGIN.+", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

I then use a loop to add each string to a list:

```
for line in file:
    match = compiler.match(line)
    if match:
        list.append(str(match.group(1)))
```

But I keep getting an empty list! Any ideas why?

Help would be much appreciated, I'm new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `file` is a filepointer such as `file = open('filename.txt')`.  If that is the case then using:

```
for line in file:
```

will break each line on the newline character.  So the first three lines will be:

```
1: '     CDS             311..>428\n'
2: '                     /gene="PNR"\n'
3: '                     /codon_start=1:\n'
```

Because each line is separate, you will not match the multiline pattern unless you combine the lines.  You may want to consider using:

```
compiler = re.compile(r"^\s+CDS\s+(.+?)ORIGIN", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
fp = open('filename.txt')
all_text = fp.read()         # this reads all the text without splitting on newlines
compiler.findall(all_text)   # returns a list of all matches
```